# CSS - How to debug active/selected input elements in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am modifying an existing template to adapt some basic parameters such as colors etc.

I use Google Chrome development extension so I can right click on a particular element use Inspect option to see what CSS rules are being applied to that element.

Then I can override specific rules in my custom CSS file.

So far so good.

My question comes for certain rules, for example if I click on an input element, the border of that element changes color but I can not right click and inspect as the focus is lost and hence I can not see in Google Developer tools what rules are being applied to that element when the focus is in that element.

Which is the strategy to debug such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the element in the Chrome Inspector and there is a 'Force state...' context menu item.

Here is a video clip demonstrating how to do it. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/triggering-of-pseudo-classes

Comment: Can this be done from within the console or be applied to all elements with a specific class?

Comment: @pee2pee Only one element at a time has focus, doesn't it? So I don't think you can do that to see all the elements with a specific class through the inspector, unfortunately. You'd have to temporarily edit your CSS to remove the `:focus` selector to see all the elements as if they were focused if you needed to do that.